# mapping branches/user/* properly in subgit

Tags: git, subgit

I'm evaluating SubGit, and it looks like it imports fairly well, except that we have both standard and nonstandard branches in our SVN directory:

```
- trunk
- tags
- branches
  - test
  - JIRA_89
  - JIRA_92
  - user
    - jim
    - bob
```

There are standard branches like `branches/test` and `branches/JIRA_89`, but we also have a few branches `branches/user/jim` and `branches/user/bob`.

What's the right way to rename these user branches for a subgit import?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this configuration

```
trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
branches = branches/users/*:refs/heads/users/*
shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

or if you want `branches/users/jim` to be translated to `refs/heads/james` (and `branches/users/bob` to `refs/heads/robert`), use this config

```
trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
branches = branches/users/jim:refs/heads/james
branches = branches/users/bob:refs/heads/robert
branches = branches/users/*:refs/heads/users/*
shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

But note that in this case `branches/james` and `branches/robert` won't be translated if they exist, because `refs/heads/james` and `refs/heads/robert` names are already taken (but you also can add special rules for those branches if you want to translate them).

Comment: could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203392/using-subgit-with-repositories-having-git-directory ? I can't seem to figure out how to specify the configuration if I'm working with the usual `.git` directory, since `subgit import` doesn't allow you to specify a configuration file, and `subgit configure` won't create the files if your directory has a `.git` directory in it.