# Using subgit with repositories having .git directory

Tags: git, subgit

I'm confused how to use subgit if I want my Git repository to have a .git subdirectory.

If I use the conventional `subgit configure` + (`subgit import` or `subgit install`), it doesn't create a `.git` directory.

If I do `git init` first, then I can do `subgit import` but it won't seem to let me do `subgit configure` first, and I want to setup my configuration file so I don't have to put a bunch of stuff in the command-line for `subgit import`.

Is there a way to tell `subgit` to use the conventional `.git` directory for all the repository stuff?

Comment: Aren't you confusing bare and not bare repositories (see a short [article](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) on them)? Usually you create a bare repository with `git init --bare` command, then run `subgit configure` + `subgit install` on it (`subgit import` is just a shortcut for configure + install + uninstall). Then you clone the resulting repository with `git clone` to get a non-bare repository with working tree and `.git/` directory in it. So you mostly work with that non-bare repository. If this is not a solution, please describe where Git objects are stored.

Comment: ah, ok, thanks -- I'll read up on them.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it with `git init --bare` instead of `git init` and it worked now. Could you post this as an answer? I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always install SubGit into a [bare](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) repository. To create a bare repository use `git init --bare` command. Alternatively you can specify non-existing or empty directory to `subgit configure` command and SubGit will create a bare Git repository at it:

```
$ subgit configure --svn-url <SVN_URL> non-existing-directory.git
$ subgit install non-existing-directory.git
```

Then you should setup Apache or SSH to give access to this repository or clone it locally to get a repository with `.git/` directory and working tree.

I would also note that `subgit import` is mostly a shortcut to `subgit configure` + `subgit install` + `subgit uninstall` commands, so for just one-time import you can use

```
$ subgit import --svn-url <SVN_URL> non-existing-directory.git
```

Comment: Very helpful as I did not find mention of the clone step in the SubGit documentation.